# Customize the year in as.Date (in R)

Tags: r, as.date

I have some dates (character string) with only month and date, for example "20-May". I'm using as.Date to convert it to a date object:

```
as.Date("20-May", format = "%d-%b")
```

What I got is: `"2021-05-20"`. So R automatically sets the year to the current year. But I want to customize the year to 2019 (expect the output to be `"2019-05-20"`). How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Date` involves 'year', 'month' and 'day'.  If one of them is not specified i.e. the 'year', it gets the current 'year'.  Avoid that by `paste`ing the 'year' and specify the four-digit year `format` (`%Y`)

```
as.Date(paste0("20-May", "-2019"), format = "%d-%b-%Y")
#[1] "2019-05-20"
```

---

Or another option is to change the `year` by assigning

```
library(lubridate)
date1 <- as.Date("20-May", format = "%d-%b")
year(date1) <- 2019
date1
#[1] "2019-05-20"
```